# flask_admin change inline_models behaviour

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I want to change some existing Python code that uses `flask_admin`. One of the views uses `inline_models` with the `(ClassName, Options)` declaration pattern. The inlined class has, amongst others, a text field.
I want to change the flask_admin default behaviour in the following ways:

- I want to make the text field read-only. I.e. still display it, but prevent the user from changing existing content.
- I do not want to allow users to delete instances of the inlined class, i.e. I want to get rid of the "Delete?" checkbox next to every entry.
- I want to override the default "Add Item" button behaviour with some custom JavaScript.

I did some Googling around but anything that looked potentially promising also looked very non-trivial. I'm hoping for some reasonably straight forward way to achieve this.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Yeesh. It looks like we're out in poorly-documented territory, here. It's hard to know if I'm improving on what you've already found, but I'll hope you're looking for something easier than writing a custom administrative view template.

1. Following the calls, it looks like the options dictionary eventually gets passed to the constructor of [InlineBaseFormAdmin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/form.py) where the various [form_* keys](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/) are extracted and applied (not sure all are respected, but I see at least `form_base_class, form_columns, form_excluded_columns, form_args, form_extra_fields, form_rules, form_label, form_column_labels, form_widget_args`). I think you can accomplish what you need via `form_widget_args`, but you can probably also get there via `form_rules` or by overriding InlineBaseFormAdmin's `get_form` or `postprocess_form` methods:

   ```
   class SomeModelView(MyBaseModelView):
       ...
       inline_models = [(db.SomeOtherModel, {
           "form_widget_args": {
               "uneditable_field_name": {"readonly": True}
           }
       })]
       ...
   ```
2. The delete option can be controlled by providing your own inline form model to override `display_row_controls`:

   ```
   from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.form import InlineModelConverter
   from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.fields import InlineModelFormList

   class CrouchingTigerHiddenModelFormList(InlineModelFormList):
       def display_row_controls(self, field): return False

   class MyInlineModelConverter(InlineModelConverter):
       inline_field_list_type = CustomInlineModelFormList

   #adding to above example
   class SomeModelView(MyBaseModelView):
       ...
       inline_model_form_converter = MyInlineModelConverter
       inline_models = [(db.SomeOtherModel, {
           "form_widget_args": {
               "uneditable_field_name": {"readonly": True}
           }
       })]
       ...
   ```

   NOTE: The widget args, such as readonly, are getting passed on to wtforms as [render_kw](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__init__), but at a blush the WTForms docs aren't clear that these get expressed as attributes in the resulting HTML input element (so any [HTML input element attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) are valid here).
3. It looks like [form.js](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/static/admin/js/form.js) controls this behavior, so you should be able to monkey-patch its `addInlineField` method to execute your own code before or after the model addition. You could override the create and/or edit templates for this--but if you're using flask-admin 1.5.0+, this might be as simple as adding `extra_js = ["your-custom.js"]` to the view class (caution: it looks like this script gets included on *every* page for this view).